# remove padding in html list

Tags: html, css, web

I have added an unordered list inside a div and I have removed its bullets. Now I want to remove space between the div and list so that the list can be shifted to left corner. Can anyone suggest me how to remove left space/gap between list and the div. Thanks

```
                    <div class="divLeftPanel">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Location</li>
                            <li>Bangalore</li>
                            <li><br/></li>
                            <li>Work area</li>
                            <li>IT</li>
                            <li><br/></li>
                            <li>Employment type</li>
                            <li>Regular full time</li>
                            <li><br/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is my css

```
.divLeftPanel{
   float: left; 
   height: 100%;
   width:30%;
   padding-left: 0px;
}
ul
{
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: used to padding-left:0; if does't work than show your code

Comment: padding-left:0px is not working here

Comment: check to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/2U3Ww/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have provided `padding` to div then use like this

```
div
{
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

and if your list has margin from left then you can do this

```
#myList
{
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

In Simple words :

> padding define the space between the element border and the element content. whereas margin define the space around elements.

EDIT: Reset css for ul like this

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zfJQc/)

Comment: For normal cases its correct but in above case this css is not working.

Comment: @PuneetPurohit got your problem. I have updated my answer. have a look

Answer (score 1):

**Now used to this**

Define your `.divLeftPanle ul` `padding-left:0;`

```
.divLeftPanel ul{padding-left:0;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/2U3Ww/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I found a solution and thanks to @sachin. I have added
     ul{padding:0px;} 
and now its working. once again thanks